# Swift put Html code to URL

Tags: html, swift, webview

I have Html form like this :

```
<form action="https:..." method="post">
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
    <input name=".." value="nil" type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
    <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
    <input type=".." value="PPP" style="background: #3aaf42; border: none; color: #fff; text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 5px; margin: -15px 0 0 -50px; display: block; top: 50%; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; left: 50%;\"/>
</form>
```

This form I want to display in `UIWebView`

Im try to put it on URL

```
let myURL = URL(string: "<form...")
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
webView.load(myRequest)
```

But can't, help me please

Comment: Must be use `webView.loadHTMLString("<form...", baseURL: nil)`

Comment: @a.masri    It does not help, because it have many "" and xCode show error

Comment: I'm  add answer see her

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

1) Edit string same this

> If you use the swift 4 version or above you can use this

```
        var myHtml  = """
<form action="https:..." method="post">
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
        <input name=".." value="nil" type="hidden"/>
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden"/>
        <input name=".." value=".." type="hidden">
        <input type=".." value="PPP" style="background: #3aaf42; border: none; color: #fff; text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 5px; margin: -15px 0 0 -50px; display: block; top: 50%; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; left: 50%;\"/>
        </form>
"""
```

> If you use less than swift 4 you can use this

```
    var myHtml  = "<form action=\"https:...\" method=\"post\">" +
     "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\"/>" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\"/>" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\">" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"nil\" type=\"hidden\"/>" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\"/>" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\"/>" +
    "<input name=\"..\" value=\"..\" type=\"hidden\">" +
    "<input type=\"..\" value=\"PPP\" style=\"background: #3aaf42; border: none; color: #fff; text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 5px; margin: -15px 0 0 -50px; display: block; top: 50%; border-radius: 3px; position: absolute; left: 50%;\\\"/>"
```

2) You should use

```
 webView.loadHTMLString(myHtml, baseURL: nil)
```

Not this, These are used to request  url

```
let myURL = URL(string: "<form...")
 let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
 webView.load(myRequest)
```